# Ruby convert csv to array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert this csv file:

```
cash,units,boxes,type
12,1,4,"beer"
12,5,4,"wine"
6,3,2,"sugar"
6,5,2,"oats"
```

to an array of just the rows and **not** the header. How does one do this?

I have this:

```
csv = CSV.read(input_path, headers: with_headers)
```

which gives me a csv object with 5 rows. How do I just convert the content to an array of 4 arrays, where each subarray represents a row?

Comment: I believe @steenslag's answer gives the correct result whereas the answer you selected does not (e.g., `[12, 1, 4, "beer"]`, not `["12", "1", "4", "beer"]`). No?

Answer (score 7):

Simply convert the enumerator returned by CSV#each to an array, and shift it to get rid of the headers.

```
rows = CSV.open(input_path).each.to_a
rows.shift
rows
=> [["12", "1", "4", "beer"], ["12", "5", "4", "wine"], ["6", "3", "2", "sugar"], ["6", "5", "2", "oats"]]
```

If you prefer a more elegant solution and actually want to treat headers as such:

```
CSV.open(input_path, headers: true, return_headers: false).map(&:fields)
```

Please mind that in this case `.each` would yield `CSV::Row` objects, not arrays.

Comment: I don't want the headers though.

Comment: Corrected, headers gone.

Comment: You need to update your return value as it still shows the headers as the first element of the array that is returned. I suggest `drop(1)` rather than `shift` as it avoid the need for the line `rows`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for pointing out the return value, corrected.

Comment: `each.to_a.map` is `duplicitous` where `map` would be sufficient. Right now it is `Enumerator` -> `Array` -> `Array` but since `CSV` includes `Enumerable` just `map(&:fields)` will return the `Array`

Comment: @engineersmnky good point, that's 2 method calls less. Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 4):

```
require "csv"

 p csv = CSV.table("test.csv").drop(1)
```

Output starts with `[[12, 1, 4, "beer"],`. that is: numbers where possible, not strings everywhere.

Comment: Readers: see the doc for [CSV::table](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-table) It's the same as [CSV::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), except (as shown), three of the `options` keys are assigned default values, one being `converters: :numeric`, which converts `"1" #=> 1`, `"1.4 #=> 1.4`, `"cat" => ."cat"` and so on. The various options are documented for `CSV::new`.

Comment: Side note `CSV` includes `Enumerable` so `CSV.table("test.csv").drop(1)` is sufficient over `to_a.drop(1)`  which causes `Array` -> `Array`

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about this, but I would solve it in this way

```
CSV.read(path, {:row_sep => :auto, :col_sep => ','}).drop(1)
```

In your case I believe you have to indicate ',' in the attribute `:col_sep`

Comment: `:col_sep` defaults to `","` which makes reasonable sense given "CSV" is traditionally an acronym for "Comma Separated Values"

Comment: If you're not sure about something its better suited as a comment than an answer.